# Can't find reference of hash in qstr structure

Tags: c, linux-kernel, filesystems, vfs

As you can see in http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9.5/fs/namei.c#L1751

```
    for(;;) {
            struct qstr this;
            long len;
            int type;

            err = may_lookup(nd);
            if (err)
                    break;

            len = hash_name(name, &this.hash);
```

at the last line, I never find struct qstr has a member name hash, only thing I found is:

```
struct qstr {
        union { 
                struct {
                        HASH_LEN_DECLARE;
                };
                u64 hash_len;
        };
        const unsigned char *name;
};
```

can anyone tell me what happened?

Comment: And you checked the `HASH_LEN_DECLARE` macro?

Comment: What does `HASH_LEN_DECLARE` expand to? I bet that declares `hash`.

Comment: And **what** does the title has to do with the question?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Very sorry, this post was edited on a draft of previous question, forgot to change the title.

Comment: Yes, forgot to check HASH_LEN_DECLARE, it defines hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/dcache.h#L30) you can find that `HASH_LEN_DECLARE` is defined as:

```
/* The hash is always the low bits of hash_len */
#ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#define HASH_LEN_DECLARE u32 hash; u32 len;
#else
#define HASH_LEN_DECLARE u32 len; u32 hash;
#endif
```

if little-endian *(machine stores the least significant byte first)* `hash` is the first member, else `hash` is the last member.